# Subqueries for a concert database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of Concerts in Oracle DB which contain the attributes ID/City/Artist/Price. I'm trying to write a query to see whether a certain City has seen three of the same artists (meaning I only need to check if any three artists have had at least one event in that city).

```
select City 
from Concerts A
where exists (select Artist from Concerts B where B.City = A.City)
and exists (select Artist from Concerts C where C.City = A.City)
and exists (select Artist from Concerts D where D.City = A.City);
```

The result of this query includes several values; but digging through the data tells me this isn't possible for some of the cities. What's wrong with my logic here?

Comment: Sample data and expected result would help.

Comment: For example, if I had 100 total rows in the table, with some having City = New York, but I wanted to see if three artists I knew by name played in New York (let's say Kanye/Jay-Z/Kendrick) played in New York at any point.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be saying you want a list of cities that have hosted at least 3 different artists, but the query you provided doesn't do that, it just links the concert table to itself 3 times in identical manner. This link will always succeed in the same way and essentially is a non operation, because it asks if the table has data that exists in itself- something true for any database table with at least one row

That's why your logic doesn't work, but for a query that works something more like:

```
Select city from concert group by city having count(distinct artist)>= 3
```

May be more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each record matches itself, so you need to ensure that the records found by e.g. the B query aren't the same records that are found by the A, C, and D queries. You can use joins here:

```
select DISTINCT A.City 
from Concerts A
INNER JOIN CONCERTS B
  ON B.CITY = A.CITY AND
     B.ID <> A.ID
INNER JOIN CONCERTS C
  ON C.CITY = A.CITY AND
     C.ID <> A.ID
INNER JOIN CONCERTS D
  ON D.CITY = A.CITY AND
     D.ID <> A.ID;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b75cf2/1)

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Self join and Desire appropriate Output.

```
   select DISTINCT A.City 
   From Concerts A,Concerts B,Concerts C,Concerts D WHERE
   A.CITY = B.CITY AND
   A.ID <> B.ID AND
   A.CITY = C.CITY AND
   A.ID <> C.ID AND
   A.CITY = C.CITY AND
   A.ID <> C.ID
```

I think this one Helpful for you.

Comment: Wow, you'd join a table to itself four times just to see if a row occurred more than 3 times? That could result in millions of rows (Cartesian product) that you're then de-duping with distinct. Throw in the fact that it uses ancient 1980s style join and has a serious typo, and I'm left thinking this answer needs some considerable review (sorry; not wishing to be cruel, especially as you're new to the place)

Comment: Caius Jard ,Thank You Guide me On this thing .

Answer (score 0):

You want cities that have seen three of the *same* artist.  You should be thinking `group by`.  In this case, you can get all such pairs of cities and artists using:

```
Select city, artist
from concert
group by city, artist
having count(*) >= 3;
```

If you just want cities where this has occurred, but you don't care about the artist:

```
select distinct city
from concert
group by city, artist
having count(*) >= 3;
```

The `select distinct` is because the city could have had 3+ concerts with more than one artist.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you want three *specific* artists.  That is not quite the same and quite unclear because your original question doesn't show any artist names.

You can easily do this with `group by`/`having`:

```
select city
from concert
where artist in ('Kanye', 'Jay-Z', 'Kendrick')
group by city
having count(distinct artist) >= 3;
```